# Convert comma to semi-colon for the certain part of the string using PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, automatic-semicolon-insertion

I have a string which is such like,

```
$input = "div-item-2,4,maintype:social| heading:sdfsdf| social: 1, 2, 3 | table:Social| item:3| align:vertical| style:icon| isactive:1,8,0";
```

I would like to convert comma to semi-colon between | is start and end. This can be illustrated below by the below image,
[image: comma to semi-colon between | is start and end]

So the string will be converted as as below,

```
$output = "div-item-2,4,maintype:social| heading:sdfsdf| social: 1; 2; 3 | table:Social| item:3| align:vertical| style:icon| isactive:1,8,0";
```

There are some other example is below,

```
$input = "div-item-0,4,maintype:menu| heading:Quick, Link| table:Menu | menuid:1| align:vertical| style:icon| isactive:1,0,0";

$output = "div-item-0,4,maintype:menu| heading:Quick; Link| table:Menu | menuid:1| align:vertical| style:icon| isactive:1,0,0";
```

Same case can be below,

```
$input = "div-item-1,4,maintype:text| heading: Name | title: Learn from here| logo:/photos/20/01.jpg| description: This is some description, so you can stay with us| isactive:1,4,0";

$output= "div-item-1,4,maintype:text| heading: Name | title: Learn from here| logo:/photos/20/01.jpg| description: This is some description; so you can stay with us| isactive:1,4,0";
```

Comment: Use `preg_replace_callback` with a pattern that matches the part between pipes and use `strtr` in the replacement callback function.

Comment: you could also consider converting it into an array, and then doing a str_replace on the [1] through [5] positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to do what you want:

```
((\||(?<!^)\G)[^,|]*),(?=.*\|)
```

It looks for

- either a `|`, or the start of the string after the previous match (`\G`),
- followed by some number of non `|` or `,` characters,
- followed by a `,`
- followed by some number of characters then a `|`

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HXJFsv/1/)

Note that `\G` would normally also match the start of string, the negative lookbehind `(?<!^)` prevents it doing that.

The characters between the start of match and the `,` are captured in group 1, and the replacement string is `$1;`. In PHP:

```
echo preg_replace('/((\||(?<!^)\G)[^,|]*),(?=.*\|)/', '$1;', $input);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Rkf1N)

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
function replaceSTR( $string, $search, $replace, $separator, $start, $end ){

  /*
   * note that this is base on your sample
   * string of course your string
   * search for ,
   * replace it with ;
   * your separator is |
   * in your sample your start is 1
   * end is 3
  */

  $result = array();
  $string = explode( $separator, $string );

  foreach( $string as $key => $value ){
   if( $key < $start || $key > $end ){
    $result[] = $value;
   }else{
    $result[] = str_replace(",",";",$value);
   }
  }
  return implode("|",$result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe this expression might return the desired output:

```
$re = '/(?:^[^|]*|(?<=\|)(?:[^,]*)(?=\|)|[^|]*$|[^,\r\n]*)|(,)/m';
$str = 'div-item-2,4,maintype:social| heading:sdfsdf| social: 1, 2, 3 | table:Social| item:3| align:vertical| style:icon| isactive:1,8,0
div-item-0,4,maintype:menu| heading:Quick, Link| table:Menu | menuid:1| align:vertical| style:icon| isactive:1,0,0"
div-item-1,4,maintype:text| heading: Name | title: Learn from here| logo:/photos/20/01.jpg| description: This is some description, so you can stay with us| isactive:1,4,0';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

$output = '';
foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
    if ($value[1] == ',') {
        $output .= ';';
    } else {
        $output .= $value[0];
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

#### Output

```
string(413) "div-item-2,4,maintype:social| heading:sdfsdf| social: 1; 2; 3 | table:Social| item:3| align:vertical| style:icon| isactive:1,8,0div-item-0,4,maintype:menu| heading:Quick; Link| table:Menu | menuid:1| align:vertical| style:icon| isactive:1,0,0"div-item-1,4,maintype:text| heading: Name | title: Learn from here| logo:/photos/20/01.jpg| description: This is some description; so you can stay with us| isactive:1,4,0"
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/YMxXpl/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/YMxXpl/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---